# Android Studio Flutter Better PC Requirement

Tags: android-studio

I am running flutter in android studio 3.x with 4GB RAM, but still very hard to build and run a project. So, I want to know the better RAM to use flutter in android studio 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is just the emulator. Just launch the emulator and exit the IDE.

You can use other editors like visual studio code and run the application with the command line.

```
flutter run
```

if the emulator is still too heavy, you can sideload apps to your phone to test.